# Maximum no of device token we can include in a Notification Payload

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I am implementing a server in that i have to send a push notification to multipal iOS devices.

Query
How many "device token" we can include in single Notification payload?

Answer (score 1):

You can only include a single device token for each notification payload. Unlike Google Cloud Messaging, if you want to send the same message to multiple devices, you have to send a separate message (duplicating the payload) to each device token.

You can and should, however, send multiple messages on the same connection, and since you don't have to wait for a response, this is efficient